# Open pdf in Iframe passing byte data

Tags: c#, iframe, byte

Is there any way to open pdf on `<iframe>` or `<object>` passing byte[] data? i have pdf on byte form.i am using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can handle this according to this. We can pass byte data in data of object.

```
<embed src="Path of file/(you can return file in byte form)"  width="960" height="900">
 </embed>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please share how can I provide byte array data in iframe or in embed ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just point the iframe to a specific aspx page that renders the pdf?